# Binary file parsing issue with node js with the library binary-parser

Tags: node.js, npm, binaryfiles, cobol, binary-data

I am parsing a binary file in node js using below command. However while parsing i am getting the value as in courseFees is of variable type "PIC S9(09)V99 COMP-3" and paymentTime is of variable type "PIC S9(07) COMP-3".

Please note both of them are type packed decimal. except these two rest of the fields are giving us required values

`

```
var Parser = require("binary-parser").Parser;
var imRecord = new Parser()
                .endianess("big")
                .string("studentNumber", {
                    length: 6
                })
                .string("courseFees", {
                    length: 6
                })
                .string("paymentTime", {
                    length: 4
                })
```

`

giving me the out put value as below and partially it is getting parsed

`

```
{
studentNumber: '211705',
courseFees: '\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u001a',
paymentTime: '\u0000\u0000\u0000\f'
}
```

`

Comment: What type of file is it?

Comment: i am parsing binary value stored in txt file to json using node js

fs.open('./student.txt', 'r', (error_opening_file, fd) =>

Comment: Could you paste some sample of the binary content of the file (hex values)?

Comment: ...and btw. trying to parse the BCD parts as string won't take you anywhere, since the parser tries to interpret the packed values as some character encoding, which just isn't there. Your best bet would be to parse as an array of 8 bit unsigned integers or bit-fields and continue from there...

Comment: 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030
3231 3037 3631 3030 3032 3031 3931 3132
3730 3030 3030 3030 3030 3000 0000 0080
1a43 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030 3030
3030 3030 0000 000c 3030 3030 3030 3031

Comment: Has the original file been created on an ASCII-platform? Because if not it has already undergone some EBCDIC->ASCII conversion and is broken beyond repairing.